# Databricks TypeError: Column is not iterable when sending JSON data to API

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

I am receiving TypeError: Column is not iterable when I attempt send data from databricks / Apache Spark to an HTTP REST API.

The code the generates the error is:

```
url = 'https://sandbox.atreemo.com/api/Contact/PostContact'
files = spark.read.json("abfss://testcontainer@adlsxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Product.json")

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.status_code)

TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

The full error message is as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1399516155397841> in <module>
      2 files = spark.read.json("abfss://testcontainer@adlsxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Product.json")
      3 
----> 4 r = requests.post(url, files=files)
      5 print(r.status_code)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    117     """
    118 
--> 119     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
```

The dataset that is being sent is in JSON format a looks like the following:

[image]

The dataset as table looks like the following:

[image]

Can someone let me know why I'm getting the error message?

Comment: I tried removing the files from the code as follows: r = requests.post(url, files) and I get the following error ```TypeError: object of type 'Column' has no len()```

Comment: please update the question with information what API expects - what content type should be used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send an object that `requests.post` isn't expecting to receive. The `files` argument is used to pass the list of the file objects, and you have the Spark dataframe.  If you want to send the content of the dataframe, you can call `files.collect()` to get data to your driver node, but real syntax will depend on the format of the data that is accepted by your API

Comment: thanks for getting in touch. I tried your suggestion, however I'm now getting the following error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Please add more information in API that you are using...

Comment: I added the collect as follows: r = requests.post(url, files.collect())

Comment: Hi @alex, the API is expecting the dataframe/dataset shown in the image above ... is that what you mean?

Comment: API may expect application/json content type, but in your case it’s not a valid json...

Comment: Hi @alex, I think you could be totally correct. API is expecting 'application/json, text/json
Sample:
`{
  "CtcID": 1,
  "LastName": "sample string 2",
  "CpyID": 3,
  "HonTitle": "sample string 4",
  "PositionCode": 1,
  "PositionFreeText": "sample string 6",
  "CreateDate": "2021-04-21T08:50:56.8602571+01:00",
  "ModifDate": "2021-04-21T08:50:56.8602571+01:00",
  "ModifiedBy": 1,
  "SourceID": "sample string 9",
  "OriginID": "sample string 10",
  "DoNotExport": true,
  "ParentEmailAddress": "sample string 13",
  "SupInfo": [
    {`
 But I'm sending data as shown above

Comment: Sorry about the editing of the code. I still don't know how to effectively use the mini-Markdown formatting